# Compare list in each row of pandas dataframe to a specific list and output to a separate pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list named `fruit_list`

```
[apple,orange,pineapple,banana,tomato]
```

I want to match this list with the pandas dataframe column named `fruits` and output the intersection.

And a pandas dataframe with column named `fruits`

```
fruits
[apple,mango]
[mango,cabbage,pineapple,carrot]
[egg,sandwich,orange,carrot,tomato]
```

Expected output

```
output      
[apple]
[pineapple]
[orange,tomato]
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, are the fruits in the array `strings` or `variables` with the names of fruits?

Comment: they are `strings` @MarceloPaco

Answer (score 3):

`map` with filter function which I think is an efficient solution

```
df['fruits'].map(lambda s: [x for x in s if x in fruit_list])
```

---

```
0             [apple]
1         [pineapple]
2    [orange, tomato]
Name: fruits, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and define a `function`:

```
def in_fruits(row, lst):
    ret_lst = []
    for f in row:
        if f in lst:
            ret_lst.append(f)
    return ret_lst

interest_fruits = ['apple','orange','pineapple','banana','tomato']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':[['apple', 'mango'], ['mango', 'cabbage', 'pineapple', 'carrot'], ['egg', 'sandwich', 'orange', 'carrot', 'tomato']]})
df1.Fruits.apply(lambda x: in_fruits(x, interest_fruits))
```

It returns the following:

```
0             [apple]
1         [pineapple]
2    [orange, tomato]
Name: Fruits, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `set.intersection` or `&` for getting the common fruits

```
df.fruits.apply(lambda x: list(set(x) & set(fruit_list)))
```

The output is

```
0             [apple]
1         [pineapple]
2    [orange, tomato]
Name: fruits, dtype: object
```